# Pwnhammer disappeared from my inventory, how do I get it back?

Tags: terraria

So I was in a normal world, playing singeplayer. I killed the Wall of Flesh 2 days ago; therefore the world was on hard mode. I obtained the Pwnhammer, but when I switched the Pwnhammer to another inventory slot, it just disappeared! Finding another Pwnhammer is really hard, so does anyone know how I can get my Pwnhammer back?

Comment: Punctuation and proper grammar are your friends.  This is almost completely incoherent.

Comment: You may have accidentally hit the button that tosses it out of your inventory. If you already left that world since it went missing, it's gone forever.

Answer (score 3):

The Pwnhammer is a 100% drop from the Wall of Flesh, so killing him again by dropping another voodoo doll in the lava will allow you to get another one.

However, if you've already smashed some altars since you got the Pwnhammer, it may not be necessary to go hunting for another one. The [Hammush](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hammush) can do anything a Pwnhammer can do, and is available for purchase from the Truffle after killing one mechanical boss.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to either kill the Wall of Flesh until you get it, or use an inventory editor.